# How to wrap multiple textviews in a single cell within a table view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I need to have a series of text views wrap within a single cell on a table but I cannot figure out how to make the text views stay in one cell and wrap depending on if the whole text view will fit on the same line. Each category name is a link to another activity and each event text view is a link to another activity. This table is built dynamically also so that may provide some restrictions.

Here is a test layout I have tried to make to figure out what settings need to be set.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Category"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Events"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="A"
            android:id="@+id/textView5" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Event 1"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 2"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:text=", Event 3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 4"
                android:id="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 5"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Event 1"
                android:id="@+id/textView11" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
             />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Event 1"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 2"
                android:id="@+id/textView13" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:text=", Event 3"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 4"
                android:id="@+id/textView15" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=", Event 5"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Update:

Still after a week of fiddling I am still not able to get my table to display correctly. I am getting all of my individual eruptions parsed out correctly but still can't get them to wrap to a new line like they do on our webpage when the number of eruptions for a single geyser exceeds the number that can fit on that line. Here is the link to that table that we use on the web interface (if you change your browser size you will understand what I am after with the android app.) http://geysertimes.org/retrievedailylog.php?date=2013-06-24 . and here is my code that builds the table currently for the app.

```
List<Eruption> alleruptionssum = null;
    try {
        alleruptionssum = db.getDaySummary(CurDateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String GeyserOLD = "";
    String timeSTR = "";
    long GeyserIDOLD = 0;
    long numEruptions = 0;
    if (alleruptionssum != null) {
        if(alleruptionssum.size() !=0){
            for (Eruption eruption : alleruptionssum) {
                int Live;
                long GeyserID;
                long EruptionID;
                long EruptionUnixTime;
                long EruptionUnixTimeMilli;
                String EruptionRegTime;
                String EruptionTimeDisplay;
                String TimeInfo;
                String Geyser;

                Live = eruption.getLive();
                GeyserID = eruption.getGeyserID();
                EruptionID = eruption.getId();
                Geyser = eruption.getGeyser();
                EruptionUnixTime = eruption.getEruptionUnixtimeTime();
                EruptionUnixTimeMilli = EruptionUnixTime * 1000;
                Date EruptionDate = new Date(EruptionUnixTimeMilli);
                SimpleDateFormat EruptionTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
                EruptionTimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain"));
                EruptionRegTime = EruptionTimeFormatter.format(EruptionDate);

                TimeInfo = eruption.getTimeInfo();
                EruptionTimeDisplay = EruptionRegTime + TimeInfo;


                if(!GeyserOLD.equals(Geyser)){
                    TableRow trGeyser = new TableRow(this);
                    //Set geyser text
                    TextView tvGeyser = new TextView(this);
                    tvGeyser.setPaintFlags(tvGeyser.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
                    tvGeyser.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                    tvGeyser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000EE"));
                    tvGeyser.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_left_middle);
                    tvGeyser.setPadding(4, 2, 4, 2);
                    tvGeyser.setText(GeyserOLD);
                    final long finalGeyserID = GeyserIDOLD;
                    tvGeyser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.d("GeyserID", String.valueOf(finalGeyserID));
                            link_recent_geyser_info(finalGeyserID);
                        }
                    });
                    trGeyser.addView(tvGeyser);

                    if(!timeSTR.equals("")){
                        LinearLayout llEruptions = new LinearLayout(this);
                        llEruptions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_right_middle);
                        llEruptions.setPadding(4,2,4,2);
                        String[] eruptions = timeSTR.split(";");
                        for ( long j = 0; j < numEruptions; j++ ) {
                            String[] ParsedEruptions = eruptions[(int) j].split(",");
                            long PostErupionID = Long.parseLong(ParsedEruptions[0]);
                            String PostEruptionDisplay = ParsedEruptions[1];
                            int PostLive = Integer.parseInt(ParsedEruptions[2]);
                            TextView comma = new TextView(this);
                            comma.setText(", ");
                            comma.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                            if(j != 0){
                                llEruptions.addView(comma);
                            }
                            TextView tvTime = new TextView(this);
                            tvTime.setText(PostEruptionDisplay);
                            tvTime.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                            tvTime.setPaintFlags(tvTime.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
                            if(PostLive == 0){
                                tvTime.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                                tvTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBD00"));
                            }else{
                                tvTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000EE"));
                            }
                            final long finalEruptionID = PostErupionID;
                            tvTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Log.d("EruptionID", String.valueOf(finalEruptionID));
                                    link_eruption_detail(finalEruptionID);
                                }
                            });
                            llEruptions.addView(tvTime);
                        }
                        trGeyser.addView(llEruptions);
                        SummaryDataView.addView(trGeyser);
                    }
                    GeyserOLD = Geyser;
                    GeyserIDOLD = GeyserID;

                    timeSTR = EruptionID+","+EruptionTimeDisplay+","+Live;
                    numEruptions = 1;

                }else{
                    //add 1 to eruption counter for current geyser and add the eruption to the string
                    numEruptions = numEruptions+1;
                    timeSTR = timeSTR + ";" + EruptionID+","+      EruptionTimeDisplay+","+Live;
                }
            }
            TableRow trGeyser = new TableRow(this);
            //Set geyser text
            TextView tvGeyser = new TextView(this);
            tvGeyser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000EE"));
            tvGeyser.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_left_bottom);
            tvGeyser.setPadding(4, 2, 4, 2);
            tvGeyser.setPaintFlags(tvGeyser.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
            tvGeyser.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
            tvGeyser.setText(GeyserOLD);
            trGeyser.addView(tvGeyser);

            LinearLayout llEruptions = new LinearLayout(this);

            llEruptions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_right_bottom);
            llEruptions.setPadding(4,2,4,2);
            String[] eruptions = timeSTR.split(";");
            for ( long j = 0; j < numEruptions; j++ ) {
                String[] ParsedEruptions = eruptions[(int) j].split(",");
                long PostErupionID = Long.parseLong(ParsedEruptions[0]);
                String PostEruptionDisplay = ParsedEruptions[1];
                int PostLive = Integer.parseInt(ParsedEruptions[2]);
               //add comma between eruptions
                TextView comma = new TextView(this);
                comma.setText(", ");
                comma.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                if(j != 0){
                    llEruptions.addView(comma);
                }
                TextView tvTime = new TextView(this);
                tvTime.setText(PostEruptionDisplay);
                tvTime.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                if(PostLive == 0){
                    tvTime.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                    tvTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBD00"));
                }
                final long finalEruptionID = PostErupionID;
                tvTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        link_eruption_detail(finalEruptionID);
                    }
                });
                llEruptions.addView(tvTime);
            }
            trGeyser.addView(llEruptions);
            SummaryDataView.addView(trGeyser);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use another LinearLayout inside the TableRow, put your textViews inside this new LinearLayout

Comment: That would put every event on a new row but in my application there are sometimes up to 15-20 events for each category so that would make the table really long. So is there a way to have all the events that can fit on a line appear there and then when it fills it bumps down to a new line?

Comment: If it helps I am the person developing the mobile app for our web interface. This is the table that I am trying to replicate in android to give some better context. http://geysertimes.org/retrievedailylog.php?date=2013-07-21

Comment: I'm not fully understanding. But the way I see it you need a tablelayout, with two columns, and the second column would be a multiline textview, whose height would change depending on the length of the text.

Comment: That is correct but in the second column there are multiple textviews in that cell as each event has a different on click listener.